# Interface Builder: Resize View From NIB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a custom *UIViewController* and a corresponding view in a nib file. The view is added to the *UIWindow* directly.

```
[window addSubview:customViewController.view];
```

Sizes of the window and the view are default (**480x320** and **460x320** correspondingly).

When I create *CustomViewController* inside the nib file and check **"Resize View From NIB"** in IB Attributes tab everything works just fine.

But when I create *CustomViewController* programmmatically with *initWithNibName* message the view is not positioned on the window correctly. There is an empty stripe at the bottom. Its height is 20px. I see it's because of status bar offset.

IB handles that with **"Resize View From NIB"**. ***How to emulate that programmatically?***

It seems that IB uses some custom subclass of UIViewController. So the question: **how is "Resize View From NIB" implemented there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to make sure the view covers the whole screen, I do something like this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self view] setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

Feels like a hack, so I do it only as a last resort, when I can’t get the view to behave otherwise :)

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work for me. The same stripe at the bottom appears.

Comment: [[self view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];

This works, but looks like some kind of hardcoding.
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] returns (0, 0, 320, 480).

Comment: You should use applicationFrame instead : self.view.frame = {CGPointZero,[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size]};

Comment: it doesn't work to me too! After set this, it reverted!